# Problems with z-index with link

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have two `div`s, a `header` and a `section`, the `section` always occupies the entire screen and `header` only a small part.

Inside my `section` I have one link as you can see in the code below:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
}
#section {
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  z-index: -1;
```

```html
<div id="header">This is my header</div>
<div id="section">
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br><a href="#">Go to the link</a>
</div>
```

I need use `z-index` in my `header` because if I do not use, it does not appear, since the `section` covers the entire screen.

You can see the DEMO [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/quk37k0q/)

Before I put the code in JSFiddle my problem was that I was not able to click on the link inside my `section`, but after putting the code in JSFiddle  the link is working.

Why did this happen? and how to solve it on my website?

Comment: The code example you posted shows no issues, so what are we to help with? Also, a `z-index` on an element with the element being positioned has no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't need neither `z-index` and `position`, you can just use `height:100%` in `#section` along with `body`,`html`

or if you wish you can use `calc()` in `#section` by using `height:calc(100% - 50px)`

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  height: 50px;
}
#section {
  background: yellow;
  height: 100% /* or -  height:calc(100% - 50px) */
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  This is my header!
</div>

<div id="section">
  <a href="#">Go to the link</a>
</div>
```

Note that you had `z-index` in `#header` which wasn't being positioned

Comment: I prefer use `height:calc(100% - 50px)` and works like a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the `absolute` position of the yellow content. You have to change `top` value to make it works without `z-index` property

```
#section{
  background:yellow; 
  position:absolute; 
  top:50px; 
  bottom:0; 
  left:0; 
  right:0; 
  overflow:hidden; 
  float:left; 
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/quk37k0q/1/)

Then, `#section` is after `#header` in the DOM tree. It means it default value of `z-index` is set to `2` and `#section` has a default value of `1`. This explains why it is on the top of `#header`. You also has to add a position value, for instance `position: relative;` to the `#header` to make it works with changing the order of elements.

[Fiddle with change of position in the DOM tree](https://jsfiddle.net/quk37k0q/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Can you just update your CSS to not use z-index and apply the background color to the BODY tag?
[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stevenng/quk37k0q/2/)

```
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
body {
  background:yellow; 
}
#header{
width:100%; 
background:green; 
height:50px; 
}
#section{
  // Intentionally blank
}
```